# Prove $\lvert s_n-s_m \rvert \le a_{m+1}$ for $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{n+1} \ge a_n \ge 0$ and $lim_{n \to \infty} = 0$. $s_n= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k$

For $n \gt m \ge 0$ prove that $\lvert s_n-s_m \rvert \lt a_{m+1}$

I am now trying to prove $a_{m+1} \ge \lvert \sum_{m+1}^n (-1)^ka_k \rvert$

Comment: So, what have you done to solve it?

Comment: @Elnur I updated it but I could not have done much

Comment: $a_n < 0 \ \forall \ n$? Because $a_n$ is nondecreasing and converging to zero. Check again what you've written. I suppose there are typos

Comment: @Elnur yes there was. I just fixed it. I am sorry

Comment: Again there is a contradiction. If $a_n > 0 \ \forall n$, then $\lim a_n \ge 0$, but you've written that limit of $a_n$ is strictly 0. Are you sure $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$? I suppose the reverse inequality should hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming it's $a_n \ge a_{n+1} \ge 0$, as Elnur mentioned) Show by induction on $m$ that $s_n \ge s_{m} \ge s_{m+1} \ge s_{n+1}$ if $n$ and $m$ are even.